# Adding BroadcastReceiver to MainActivity is not working

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

In my project, I have 2 activities. From main activity I will launch 2nd activity with a native VideoView in it, and in onCreate method i will call finish so that i will run in back ground. But I want to send updates to MainActivity back, like pause, start, stop.. etc. I found out `BroadcastReceiver` is the best way to address this issue. Here is what I am doing, but MainActivity does not receive broadcast sent by 2nd Activity, here is my code.

In MainActivity.java,

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        System.out.println("In onReceive");
    }
};
private IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.example.broadcast");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
}
```

In 2nd Activity,

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.broadcast");
intent.putExtra("Status", status);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Register the receiver like: `LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);`

Comment: Most likely, `MainActivity` isn't active when the second `Activity` is displayed. Where do you unregister the receiver?

Comment: @bigdestroyer, I can not add `LocalBroadcastManager`, as it is not resolving in Android Studio.

Comment: @323go, when I call finish() on 2nd Activity, it is displaying MainActivity, so I think MainActivity is active.

Comment: In second Activity, do you send broadcast after or before finish()?

Comment: @Krish : Urrm, How can the 2nd Activity send broadcasts if it has been terminated using `finish()`?

Comment: But 2nd Activity is still running in the background, because the video is playing.

Comment: @Krish : No, when you call `finish()` in an `Activity` it self-terminates.

Comment: @Krish : How can the video still be playing if the `Activity` is finished? Can you see the video or are you just hearing the audio track?

Comment: @Squonk, I can not see the video, but i can get the callbacks form player in the background.

Comment: Thanks for your views guys, now I get it working, I am sending broadcasts from 2nd Activity before I call finish() on it as well as after calling finish(). So MainActivity only receives broadcasts only when it is active, (i.e. when 2nd Activity goes to background.)

Comment: @Krish : **"when 2nd Activity goes to background"**. When you call `finish()` in an `Activity` it does *NOT* go to "background" - it basically finishes (kills) itself. `VideoView` manages its own thread for playback which is why after the 2nd `Activity` is finished, if you haven't cleaned up the `VideoView`, then the `VideoView` is still functional. I suggest you read some more about the life-cycle of the Android `Activity` class.

Comment: @Squonk, oh I see, but my idea is to have the `VideoView` running till the video gets completed, so then I can clean the view up, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

The moment you send that broadcast, the first activity is paused, so it can't receive it. It gets resumed only after you 2nd activity terminates using finish().

If you want to compute something in background, you can use a `Service`.

I don't  know why you may want to play a video in background, but you could put the View in your 1st activity and set the views visibility to invisible.

(Actually I thought of a reason just now, good idea if you think what I'm thinking)

Comment: If i make the visibility of a view to invisible, will the video still play?

Comment: Didn't try it, but I think it will, as it is still there. Only if you set it to "gone" it will completely disappear, then I'm not sure it will continue. "Invisible" = still there but you can't see it <-> "gone" = not there anymore.